# SQL / Regex string transformation

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql

Hi does anyone know in SQL Server, MySQL or even Postgresql how to transform the string:

`'TEST TEST529932******2018'`

into

`'TEST TEST\d{6}******\d{4}'`

The key is to replace all the digits in the string with the regex \d{N} where N is the number of digits.

Comment: Agreed @GordonLinoff

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are looking to anonymize the string in a way that regular expressions will match, then you can just replace each digit with `\d` or `[0-9]`.  That can easily be done:

```
select regexp_replace(str, '[0-9]', '\d', 'g')
from (values ('TEST TEST529932******2018')) v(str)
```

This produces:

```
'TEST TEST\d\d\d\d\d\d******\d\d\d\d'
```

I'm not sure if this meets you actual need.

One approach is to use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select regexp_replace(str, '(^|[^0-9])[0-9]', '\1\d{1}', 'g') as str, 1 as lev
      from t 
      union all
      select regexp_replace(str, '\\d\{' || lev || '\}[0-9]', '\d{' || (lev + 1) || '}', 'g'), lev + 1
      from cte
      where str ~ '[^{][0-9]'
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7017fb03a3a3c7de57d8c93812321f6c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi Gordon this is very close to what I am after. Is there anyway to make '\d\d\d\d' become d{4} for example and get to this structure 'TEST TEST\d{6}******\d{4}'

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thank you.